# AHF Formatter: Prevent line-break for hyphenated words

Tags: xsl-fo, hyphenation

Is it possible to prevent line breaks inside hyphenated words (XML content) with the Antenna House Formatter? I thought of a solution with a RegEx but don´t know if this is even possible with the AHF.

E.g. the author provides the following: `<paragraph>the film we are producing is a very low-budget one</paragraph>`

In this case I want to keep the word "**low-budget**" together in line (like it does here on stackoverflow). But AHF displays it as **low-** (1st line) and **budget** (2nd line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's multiple alternatives:

- Use `hyphenate="false"` to turn off hyphenation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#hyphenate).  Since `false` is its initial value, your question implies that you have hyphenation turned on and do want to hyphenate other words.
- If you do have `hyphenate="true"` to enable hyphenation, you can either replace the `-` in the existing hyphenated words with `&#x2011;` (U+2011, NON-BREAKING HYPHEN) or wrap each hyphenated word with an `fo:wrapper` or `fo:inline` that has `hyphenate="false"`.

  If you want to replace *all* hyphens in the output with `&#x2011;`, you can use a character map in your XSLT (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps), otherwise you could selectively replace the character using `replace()`, as you suggest.

  If you use `&#x2011;` and don't want your hyphenated words hyphenating at other points, you probably also want to stop that by using `axf:hyphenate-hyphenated-word="false"` (https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.hyphenate-hyphenated-word).

Comment: thumbs up for the AHF extentions. thanks - the character map will do the trick.